# SQL code for fin, copy and paste :

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i have two tables ...

Helpfull table:

```
SELECT * FROM 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00006;

CISLO    NAME
WO01       one
WO02       four
WO03       tree                  (other cells)
```

Acctive table

```
SELECT * FROM 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00008;

TEXT                                          NAME
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 3x1,7W WW > WO01        NULL
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW > WO02        NULL
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW - WO03        NULL                  (other cells)
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW / WO04        NULL
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW + WO05        NULL
```

And i need create a SQL code which i can find row in table00008 which in the TEXT has data from CISLO from table00006 and copy value in NAME by matching CISLO>TEXT

result:

```
TEXT                                          NAME
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 3x1,7W WW WO01        one
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW WO02        four
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW WO03        tree                  (other cells)
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW WO04        NULL
Osvetlenie LED SMARTBAR 2x1,7W WW WO05        NULL
```

Can anyone help me I have desperately Thx, Martin

Comment: MySQL or SQL-Server? It can't be both. Is the TEXT always at the end of the column, or can it be anywhere?

Comment: can by anywhere ... :)

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL you can write a join and update as:

```
--First check if you get desired results:
Select T1.Text ,T2.CISLO ,T2.Name 
FROM @skladovekarty00008 as T1 
join @skladovekarty00006 as T2 on T1.Text like  N'%' + T2.CISLO + N'%';


--If T2.Name are the values with which you want to replace T1.Name then write as
Update T1
Set T1.Name = T2.Name 
FROM @skladovekarty00008 as T1 
join @skladovekarty00006 as T2 on T1.Text like  N'%' + T2.CISLO + N'%';
```

[Demo.](http://rextester.com/KIDHF99668)

Comment: hmmm ... this solution is probably not good for me or I do not get it .... I already have created the tables and one table has 25,000 rows and the other has 12,000 rows. And just those 12000 lines I put in the 25000

Comment: First question : are you using SQL Server? If yes, then don't go with the create/ insert statements above as that was just to create a sample of data at my end. Try update statemnt ..it should help.

Comment: thank, you and yes i have SQL server ... but still i do not understand what to must do ...

Comment: i have problem with syntax in Mysql Workbench, 6.1.6

Comment: On "Select" i have syntaxx error >>>join @skladovekarty00006 as T2 on T1.Text like  N'%' + T2.CISLO + N'%';<<<

Answer (score 0):

Now try this one for your scenario.

```
UPDATE b  
SET b.NAME = a.NAME  
FROM  
36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00006 a   
join  
36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00008 b  
ON a.CISLO = SUBSTRING(REVERSE(b.TEXT),0,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(b.TEXT))-1)
```

I beleive you would have had some relationship to join these two tables. IF so try the below one.
[For the case of CISLO in TABLE 'skladovekarty00006' can be anywhere in TEXT of TABLE 'skladovekarty00008']

```
UPDATE b  
 SET b.NAME = CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%a.CISLO%',b.TEXT) > 0 THEN a.NAME END  
 FROM  
 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00006 a  
 join  
 36496839_radioamater.skladovekarty00008 b  
ON a.keycol = b.keycol
```

Comment: Relatioship is not based on some other key column but on the fact that data in CISLO column should match (partially) with data in Text column of another table.