# Syntax error MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Please help with this >

```
--First check if you get desired results:
Select T1.Text ,T2.CISLO ,T2.Name 
FROM @skladovekarty00008 as T1 
join @skladovekarty00006 as T2 on T1.Text like  N'%' + T2.CISLO + N'%';


--If T2.Name are the values with which you want to replace T1.Name then write as
Update T1
Set T1.Name = T2.Name 
FROM @skladovekarty00008 as T1 
join @skladovekarty00006 as T2 on T1.Text like  N'%' + T2.CISLO + N'%';
```

Mysql Workbench always giving syntax error, so i don´t understand where is error ...

Comment: Please paste the error in your post.

Comment: since when does mysql use `+` for concatenation? You need to use the `concat` function... and `N'%'` means nothing in mysql either.

Comment: This code advised me to solve my problem [link to problem HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947917/sql-code-for-fin-copy-and-paste/)

Comment: mysql != t-sql. You cannot take an mssql query and stuff it into mysql and expect it to work.

Comment: Please advise me so how can I do to make it work, I am a beginner and I'm learning ...